# C# / Unity : Visual Studio parameter not getting passed

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Problem Overview: Parameter passed to function is not making it to the function

I have a function call in one script that calls another. The caller is shown below- 
[image: Caller Code]

However, the function which gets called (and I am sure that it is being called due to stepping directly into the function and only stepping forwards one line at a time), never gets that variable.

[image]

Hovering over the **name** parameter does nothing, even though hovering over the **searchAllScenes** gives me a value of false. The **name** parameter similarly does not show up in Autos, and typing it into the Immediate Window returns "Unable to evaluate the expression. General Exception". It's also not being set to the default null value, as lines 265-266 are never triggered.

I feel like this is a compiler issue, and have tried rebuilding the solution, but the same problem keeps occurring, preventing my project from working. It was working a few days ago, it just stopped, with no changes made (I have git reverted back to previous versions and they do not work).

Versions:

- Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.8.9
- Unity 2018.2.14f1 Personal

Comment: Maybe try deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders, then rebuild.  Also, maybe try a `Console.WriteLine(name);` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing ended up working. I tried deleting the obj and bin folders and rebuilding, but it still did not work. However, for some reason, simply deleting the objects that were using those scripts and reimporting them made everything work again.

This isn't exactly a fix, as I still don't understand what happened, though.